# Load URL in for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I am sending a message to multiple phone numbers .
Mobile numbers are stored in an array .

```
string phNums =  "91999999999,9199999998....";.
string[] phNos = phNums.Split(',');
```

But message doesn't reach all of the recipients , mostly to the numbers that are present near end of array.
The message are sent via a URL provided by SMS service provider in which the phone number and the message is embedded.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < phNos.Length; i++)
  {
    url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dd/HTTPMTAPI?User=abc&Password=pqr&FromAddr=xyzSMS&DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message;
    Uri targetUri1 = new Uri(url);
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwb1;
    hwb1 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri1);
    hwb1.GetResponse();
  }
```

As an alternate , I also used Webclient() but still successful message delivery is not guaranteed.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < phNos.Length; i++)
  {
    WebClient cli= new WebClient();
  url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dd/HTTPMTAPI?User=abc&Password=pqr&FromAddr=xyzSMS&DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message;
    cli.DownloadString(url);
  }
```

How to ensure that message delivery is not skipped . 
Like only if successful response is received on downloading the URL , the loop should progress to next mobile number and so on.
If there is any other possible mechanism , please do suggest. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a query string parameter after the base URL and before the `phNos[i]` is added into the  `url` string? Looks like the service you are trying to use operates based on query strings, because you have the `&` for the `msg` param, but no `?` or parameter name for the phone number. I tried to google for the service youre using, but every sms provider I found that uses the &msg parameter required phone number to be passed as a query string as well, not just a number appended to the base URL.

Comment: Yes sir there is &msg parameter , I shortened the url for posting on forum..Please see updated url in post

Comment: you might need to actually read the response to see if you're getting an error, such as the service throttling you for sending too many numbers at a time.

Comment: Can I make the loop wait until I get response from loading url and then proceed to next mobile number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phNos.Length; i++)
{
    url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.dd/HTTPMTAPI?User=abc&Password=pqr&FromAddr=xyzSMS&DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message;
    Uri targetUri1 = new Uri(url);
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwb1;
    hwb1 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri1);
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = hwb1.GetResponse();
    if (response != null)
        {
            int status = (int)response.StatusCode; // this changes the status 
                                                   // from text response to the
                                                   // number, like 404
            if (status == 404//or anything else you want to test//)
               {
                    // put your retry logic here, make sure you add a way to break 
                    // so you dont infinitely loop if the service is down or something
               }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the status code if url is loaded successfully so that i can test against it.

Comment: Here is a list of all the HTTP status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html . Status 200 (OK) is *probably* what you want to test for, but I would recommend you step through the code a few times to see exactly what your service returns. Put the break point on `response != null` and `if (status =` and check the values in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

URLs have a length constraint.  Your are likely hitting this limit and your are losing the trailing phone numbers as a result.  Your best bet would be to break your requests into multiple requests of a certain size.

According to the following SO, it may be good practice to limit your request so that the url does not surpass 2000 characters.
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Comment: No url limit is not being breached because Only one mobile number embedded in a URL at a time .